Azure AD B2C Custom Policy ExternalUser is not found using ExternalAzureAD
The custom policy authentication is integrated and works fine for the users, created specifically to the current tenant. However, in case, when user is logging in using AD account from a different tenant, it throws an error, saying that the account is not found.
I have verified, that the App Registration for the SPA has the following keys set:
{
  "signInAudience": "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount",
  "accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2,
}

The error is as follows:
{
  "status":"400","errorCode":"AADB2C90053","message":"We can't seem to find your account."
}

There is another tenant setup and configured by me, that works fine with external users (from other tenants). I can't find what is the difference. Please advice.

Could you please edit your question and include more details like what code you tried? As error message indicates that Azure B2C tenant is unable to locate the account which is used for authentication
